# How can I use list slices in .format()?

Tags: python

So say that I have list a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]. But say that depending on the rest of the program, I can't be sure how long a will be, but I want to display it using .format. How could I reference the last four elements? (without reversing the list and referencing the first four.)

Comment: Same way you slice a list in any other context: `a[-4:]`.

Comment: Or `'...'.format(*a[-4:])` to unpack them as four sequential argument to some format string.

Comment: yep what @user2357112 said `a[-4::]` you missed a `:`

Comment: @MikeTung What's the difference btw the two (`::` vs `:`)? They seem to give me the same result when I run them on a list like the OP has. Thanks!

Comment: @patrick: there is no difference.  You can use `[-4:]` or `[-4::]`.  In both cases you are implicitly creating a slice object `slice(-4, None, None)` which is used to index the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want, use `[-4:]` to get the last four elements, then unpack them:

```
>>> a=range(10)
>>> "{} {} {} {}".format(*a[-4:])
'6 7 8 9'
```

Hope this helps.